# Ubuntu missing in Boot Priority Order

Tags: 12.04, boot, thinkpad, bios

I've Ubuntu 12.04 installed as my only OS on My Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon. 
Today it wouldn't boot (the screen just went black when Ubuntu booted). I resat the BIOS to default and tried booting again - now 'ubuntu' disappeared from the boot list, and I'm not able to boot anything anymore.
Is there any fix for this? It's a pretty bad situation..

Cheers,
Adrian

Comment: First try boot-repair.If there any black screen appears on boot then try http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it.

Comment: How do I perform a boot-repair?

Comment: try the second option in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply - too bad that I haven't a computer at my service ATM

Answer (score 0):

follow this steps :

1. boot with the live cd of ubuntu.
2. choose "try ubuntu".
3. use this command in a terminal to install an application named "boot-repair" *sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair -y && sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair*
4. after this command finish her work you will see that an application just started in your pc.
5. now in this application, clique on "recommended reparation" and wait for it to finish her work.
6. reboot now and see if ubuntu is back on the boot list, if he isn't you can try to recover your data then install ubuntu again.